# Convergent Series 2n-1/2n

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Prove the series defined by P(n) = (1 *3 * 5 *** (2n-1))/(2*4*6 *** (2n)) is convergent

It is monotone decreasing and bounded below by zero, but is that enough to say?

Comment: You can simplify $\frac{2n-1}{2n}$ to $1-\frac{1}{2n}$, if that helps.

Comment: I have to use the definition of convergence.

Comment: The sequence is not decreasing. It is increasing.

Comment: The OP did not say so, but my guess is that $P(n)$ is the $n$-th partial sum. The limit of these is $1$, and to make the difference less than $\epsilon$, it is enough to let "$N$" be an integer $\gt \frac{1}{2\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 9):

Note that

$$\displaystyle \ln \Pi_{n=1}^N \frac{2n-1}{2n}=\sum_{n=1}^N \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)\le -\frac12 \sum_{n=1}^N\frac 1n,$$ where we have used the known inequality $\ln(1+x)\le x,$ which holds for any $x>-1.$  Now, $s_N=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac 1n\to \infty$ as $N\to \infty.$ Thus  $$\displaystyle \ln \Pi_{n=1}^N \frac{2n-1}{2n}\le -\frac12 s_N,$$ or equivalently,

$$\displaystyle \Pi_{n=1}^N \frac{2n-1}{2n}\le e^{-1/2s_N}.$$ Since the product is nonnegative and $-1/2s_n\to -\infty$ we conclude that

$$\displaystyle \Pi_{n=1}^N \frac{2n-1}{2n}\to 0.$$

Comment: Note IT is not the sum...it is the multiplication of terms. My bad

Comment: That is precisely the reason that mfl takes the natural logarithm of your expression: to convert the product into a sum!

Answer (score 2):

The **sequence** $P(n)$ is convergent, the **series** $\sum P(n)$ is divergent.

From inequality of arithmetic and geometric means:
$$\sqrt{1\cdot 3}\leq 2,\ \sqrt{3\cdot 5}\leq 4,\ldots, \sqrt{(2n-3)(2n-1)}\leq 2n-2.$$
Multiplying them we obtain
$$1\cdot 3\cdots (2n-3)\sqrt{2n-1}\leq 2\cdot 4\cdots (2n-2)$$.
Therefore
$$P(n)\leq \frac{\sqrt{2n-1}}{2n}.$$
This shows that $P(n)\to 0$. On the other hand, similarly (using $\sqrt{2\cdot 4}\leq 3$, etc.), one can show that
$$P(n)\geq \frac 1{2\sqrt n}.$$
This shows that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(n)=\infty.$$

Comment: Your answer an almost 8 year old question, and your answer adds nothing new.  I encourage you to answer more current posts.  You've got the formatting and knowledge to do so.