# Limit of the Product $\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I know I can transform the above product as follows

\begin{eqnarray*}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{5}{6}...\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)\\&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)\\&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{-1/2}{k}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

My thoughts are this is going to go to $e^{-x/2}$, but I can't figure out how to go from

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{-1/2}{k}\right)$$

to

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{-1/2}{n}\right)^n$$

Comment: The product does not exhibit exponential decay.  It goes down like the inverse of the square-root function.  Plot it and you will see what I mean.

Comment: isn't the inverse of the square root function the square function?

Comment: or do you mean the multiplicative inverse?

Comment: Yes, I meant the multiplicative inverse (i.e., the reciprocal).

Comment: see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1044116/515527

Comment: Alternatively: $$\prod_{k=1}^n\,\left(\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n+1)!!}=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n (n!)^2}$$ And now use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: @Zacky  I have recently realized that Stirling's approximation and Wallis's product imply each other.  If you know one, then you can prove the other.  It's quite neat.

Comment: That's wonderful, I will look  after it.

Comment: @Zacky  This is what I was talking about: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078873/using-wallis-formula-to-show-the-limit-of-a-n-n-left-fracen-rightn-n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wallis's Product Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product)
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\,\left(\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)\,\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right)=\frac2\pi\,,$$
we see that
$$(2m+1)\,\left(\prod_{n=1}^m\,\left(\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)\right)^2=\prod_{n=1}^m\,\left(\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)\,\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right)\approx \frac{2}{\pi}\,.$$
Consequently,
$$\prod_{n=1}^m\,\left(\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)\approx\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi(2m+1)}}\,.$$
For comparison plots, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DiscretePlot%5B%7BProduct%5B1-1%2F(2*k),%7Bk,1,n%7D%5D,Sqrt%5B2%2FPi*1%2F(2n%2B1)%5D%7D,%7Bn,1,100%7D%5D) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DiscretePlot%5BProduct%5B1-1%2F(2*k),%7Bk,1,n%7D%5D%2FSqrt%5B2%2FPi*1%2F(2n%2B1)%5D,%7Bn,1,100%7D%5D).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prove that the limit goes to zero using exponentials, as you mention in your question, then take the $\ln$, let
$$a_n = \prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)$$ 
then call
$$b_n = \ln a_n = \ln \prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \ln \big( 1 - \frac{1}{2k} \big) $$ We know that $\ln(1-x) \leq -x$. So 
$$b_n \leq -\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$
Now let $c_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$, which is the harmonic series and we know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} c_n = + \infty$. Take exponentials on both sides of the above equation, we get
$$a_n \leq e^{-\frac{1}{2} c_n}$$
Now, the limit is 
$$0 \leq \lim a_n \leq \lim e^{-\frac{1}{2} c_n} = e^{-\infty} = 0$$

So, by the Sandwich theorem,  the limit goes to zero.

NOTE: @Batominovski gives another approach on how the product behaves asymptotically, i.e. as $\prod_{n=1}^m\,\left(\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)\approx\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi(2m+1)}}\,.$, which (in my opinion) is more interesting.